# (Jupyter Notebook, LaTeX) LaTeX pdf compilation error MiKTeX209-xetex.dlll not found

Tags: latex, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, xelatex

I am using Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda and when I tried to download as pdf via LaTeX, I obtain the following error:

[image: LaTeX compilation error in Jupyter]

Is there a known way to resolve this error? I tried reinstalling but still obtained the same error. Also, I tried to look it up online but to the best of my knowledge, no one has yet to encounter the problem I have.

Looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68041/miktex-cannot-find-the-file but I still can't seem to figure it out..

Comment: Did you try reinstalling MiKTeX?

Comment: @darthbith Yes. I reinstalled both Anaconda as well as MiKTeX once, and the error message still appears.